# Can I use a US visa in my old Kenya passport after being issued the new East African Community passport?

Tags: visas, usa, kenyan-citizens, valid

Due to a directive by the Kenya government, old Kenyan passports must be converted to new East African Community passports before September 2019. The old passports will no longer be used after 01 September 2019. I applied and got a new East African Community passport.

My Kenya passport has a valid B2 visa. Do I need to get the visa transferred to new passport or can I travel with both passports to enter USA??

Answer (score 4):

You can travel with both passports to the US.  See [About Visas - The Basics](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html):

> Visa Validity
>
> My old passport has already expired. My visa to travel to the United States is still valid but in my expired passport. Do I need to apply for a new visa with my new passport?
>
> No. If your visa is still valid you can travel to the United States with your two passports, as long as the visa is valid, not damaged, and is the appropriate type of visa required for your principal purpose of travel. (Example: tourist visa, when your principal purpose of travel is tourism). **Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the visa) should be from the same country and type (Example: both Uruguayan regular passports, both official passports, etc.).** When you arrive at the U.S. port-of-entry (POE, generally an airport or land border) the Customs and Border Protection Immigration Officer will check your visa in the old passport and if s/he decides to admit you into the United States they will stamp your new passport with an admission stamp along with the annotation "VIOPP" (visa in other passport). Do not try to remove the visa from your old passport and stick it into the new valid passport. If you do so, your visa will no longer be valid.

(emphasis added)

Let's look at the bold sentence, because there might be a question there.  It says that both passports must be issued by the same country.  Since Kenya's EAC passport is issued by Kenya, it is in fact from the same country.  The EAC passport isn't issued by the EAC directly; rather, it is issued by Kenya as a member of the EAC.

There is an additional requirement that the passports be of the same type.  That is, if the visa is in a diplomatic passport, the new passport used with the visa must also be a diplomatic passport.  Unless you're traveling on government business, both of your passports will be "regular" passports.  The fact that one is an EAC passport and the other isn't doesn't mean that the passports are of a different type.

Comment: Just a small comment: it seems to me that the requirement that the expired passport (where the visa is) and the new passport should be the same type (regular and regular; or diplomatic and diplomatic) is a new thing. I say this because up until (I think) 2015, I was still able to travel to and enter the US using an expired diplomatic passport (from when I was a minor) where my 10-year B1/B2 visa was, and a regular passport.

Comment: The new passport even still says REPUBLIC OF KENYA on it, along with EAST AFRICAN COMMUNITY.

Comment: @ar5975 in fact, that requirement seems to be in conflict with the regulation ([22 CFR 41.112(b)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/41.112#b_3)), which says "An unexpired visa is valid for application for admission even if the passport in which the visa is stamped has expired, provided the alien is also in possession of a valid passport issued by the authorities of the country of which the alien is a national."

Comment: @Oh ok. Haha. Talk about conflicting information. But I can definitely attest to travelling on a regular passport with a valid B1/B2 10-year visa on an expired diplomatic passport (twice, as a matter of fact). I even got an e-mail response from the US Embassy telling me that this is possible (but also mentioning that this is not a guarantee for entry into the US).